# Fetch API Error in Service Worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker, fetch-api

I am trying to cache images from the LastFM API. Now, the API response itself is cached fine and the page loads as expected, however, there are no images.

Looking into the developer console, I can see a couple of errors regarding the retrieval of the images and they're as follows:

> Fetch API cannot load http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/300x300/a32cb06bb22bc5d10654a5156fe78cf6.png. The parent document page has been unloaded.

I'm very new to service workers and this has got me tearing my hair out (no, not literally).

I've followed a couple of tutorials and this is the code I've got so far (irrelevant code has been stripped out).

```js
var CACHE_NAME = 'WELFORDIAN-CACHE-V2';
var urlsToCache = [
  'https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&user=**USERNAME**&api_key=6136000ba0899c52db5ebcee77d4be15&format=json'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  // Perform install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
    .then(function(cache) {
      console.log('Opened cache');
      return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  var reqURL = new URL(event.request.url);
  if (/lst.fm/.test(reqURL)) {
    event.respondWith(lastFMImageResponse(event.request));
  } else {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }

        var fetchRequest = event.request.clone();

        return fetch(fetchRequest).then(
          function(response) {
            if (!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
              return response;
            }
            var responseToCache = response.clone();

            caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
              .then(function(cache) {
                cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
              });

            return response;
          }
        );
      }).catch(function(err) {
        return err;
      })
    );
  }
});

function lastFMImageResponse(request) {
  return caches.match(request).then(function(response) {
    if (response) {
      return response;
    }
    return fetch(request).then(function(response) {
      caches.open('lfm-images').then(function(cache) {
        cache.put(request, response);
      });

      return response.clone();
    });
  });
}
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but can anyone with more experience than I explain what it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your website is HTTPS, while the images are served via HTTP.

Mixed content is currently not working well with service workers: https://github.com/w3c/webappsec/issues/415.

Comment: Thank you! I solved this by serving the images via a simple PHP script which grabs the image from URL and outputs the data. You saved me so much annoyance.